# How to isolate the invalid element when validating a XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to validate an XML using php and return the errors (if any) to the sender of the XML file. The returned text should be customised as specified by the sender. For instance, if the error is in the format of the data, I get in the libxml_get_errors() message:

```
Element 'INSEE': '91m326' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:int'
```

And if the error is in a tag the message is:

```
Opening and ending tag mismatch: SINISTRE line 6 and INTERVENTION
```

How can I isolate 'INSEE' or SINISTRE in this message to use them in my customised message?